# "Thanks for participating" email is in unparsed Markdown

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown, email, beta-phase

I just received a "Thanks for participating" email for the [Proof Assistants](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/) site. I assume these are sent automatically by a script, but it seems to have missed the Markdown-to-HTML parser somehow:

[image]

Comment: Everybody can format Markdown in their head anyway, right?

Comment: Are you viewing it in HTML mode or as plain text? IIRC the way we send plain text is just use the markdown that backs the HTML version.

Comment: @AdamLear I didn't deliberately choose a mode; I see the unformatted text both on the Gmail website and the default iOS Mail app. Other emails (also ones from Stack Exchange) do show up properly formatted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For context, internally we use some automated emails to open up Jira issues.  The HTML formatting made it hard to parse into tickets, so a while back we turned off HTML for a small number of emails, and this just got caught in the cross-fire.

Thanks for the report – should be all set now.

[image: Sample email with HTML formatting]