# "Is it time to add another moderator" email contains unparsed Markdown

Tags: bug, markdown, moderators, email

I just received [another email in unparsed Markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377373/295232):

[image]

Can somebody please reactivate the Markdown parser - I seem to remember earlier emails of this type being correctly formatted.

Comment: Are you announcing an upcoming election on Board & Card Games?

Comment: @rene no. We get these emails now and then - no idea what the trigger is, though I guess it's temporal in nature.