# Email does not support SE-style Markdown, to everyone's disappointment

Tags: bug, status-review, markdown, moderators, email

I just received an email from Stack Overflow community support, checking in with me about why I haven't taken moderator activites on [Constructed Language Stack Exchange](https://conlang.stackexchange.com) lately. The answer is simple; it hasn't been necessary. (It's a [very quiet](https://conlang.stackexchange.com/admin?filter=quarter) site. I've actually handled the most flags of the whole team this year.) However, something struck me about this email (presented and formatted as I received it):

> Hello Mithical, We noticed that you haven’t been active in moderating Constructed Languages Stack Exchange over the last 4 months. That’s nothing for you to be overly concerned about – this is just an automated message letting you know that the Community Team is available to help you with any concerns you might have. Sometimes life happens, and other interests take priority over site moderator duties. That’s no problem at all. We just wanted to make sure you were aware that we have an Absentee Moderator policy in which we remove a moderator's privileges when they have been inactive for 6 months. If you haven’t picked up moderating again at that point, we’ll be reaching out to give you a heads-up that we’ll be removing your moderator diamond at that time. If there are any extenuating circumstances (like a sabbatical or vacation), you can mark yourself as temporarily on vacation [using this tool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/vacation). If you are no longer interested in moderating the site, let the Community Team know. We’ll be happy to make the necessary accommodations. We hope everything is going well for you. We truly appreciate all of the work you have put into the site as a moderator and a dedicated community member. If you need anything, please don't hesitate to contact us by emailing community-support@stackoverflow.com. Take care, The Stack Exchange Community Team Stack Overflow, 110 William Street, 28th floor, New York, NY 10038 <3

[image: Screenshot of the email, text reproduced above]

This email is formatted in Markdown. The link formatting is in Markdown, and the paragraph breaks are — I'm guessing — also. It's not unreasonable that it's written in Markdown; Stack Exchange uses Markdown for posts and mod messages, after all.
Unfortunately, email doesn't.

While I can read and write (and appreciate) Markdown as much as the next moderator, the formatting of this automated email should probably be fixed so that it displays properly in email.

Comment: Well since developers never get this email, there's no way for them to ever know it's broken until someone reports it, I bet it's like that from the moment it was published. Wonder how this can be improved, creating a sock, making it a moderator, then waiting four months doesn't sound right either. ;)

Comment: There are more moderator-only emails which don't support Markdown; I reported one a while ago: ["Is it time to add another moderator" email contains unparsed Markdown](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/381752/295232)

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars "*developers never get this email, there's no way for them to ever know it's broken*" no. "*Wonder how this can be improved*" it's an email. You can send it to anybody. There is a template and there is a recipient. Send the template to the recipient. Set the recipient to dev email. Done. Hardly "impossible" or requiring complex workarounds. Or even regular users to test this out. If whatever system SE uses does not allow sending test emails, that's a separate problem, but not a problem inherent with emails.

Comment: @VLAZ sounds so easy when you describe it, I almost wonder why SE isn't doing that. ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars we both know that SE pushes many things to productions that *should have been caught earlier* yet weren't. Have we even finished cleaning up all the encoded apostrophes? I don't want to speculate about what the precise reason for lack of proper testing is, however, we do have evidence that not catching problems is endemic.